# Alert dialog required two times back to finish activity

Tags: android

In my activity I am showing spinner when user press POWER button spinner show successfully if user select any option is work fine but when user press back its required two times back press to show original activity what do i do? how to close and finish activity just single back press???

```
public class ActivityHome extends Activity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER == event.getKeyCode() && isRooted()) {     
        startActivity(new Intent(ActivityHome.this, Spinnermenu.class));        
        return true;      
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public class Spinnermenu  extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    final String items[] = {"Power off","Restart"};
    AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(Spinnermenu.this);
    ab.setTitle("Power Options");
    ab.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int choice) {
        if(choice == 0) {       
                    Toast.makeText(Spinnermenu.this,"PowerOff Perform",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                      
        }
        else if(choice == 1) {

        }
    });
    ab.show();
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
       if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            this.finish ();
       }
       return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: in eclipse try CTRL + A then CTRL + I to fix indentation of your code

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Please do not add "Thanks in advance." to posts.

Comment: @Mikeyaworski Yes I will correct myself.

Answer (score 0):

You just put this code in your program it will do your need....

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```

All the best..

Comment: i did not wotk in debug mode when i press second time back is come at this line
 if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
         this.finish ()

Comment: telll me how to finish activity when backpress or cancil alert builder??

Comment: You will put the finish() method in the alertbox click function

Comment: suppose user not select any option just click back button then?? i think when press firsttime ack just alertdailog  close when second time click back button activity finish

Comment: how to handle this just first time when alertdailog close also finish activity

Comment: You just put finish method in both the function it will work defintely

Comment: but if user notclick any option just press back button?

Comment: You have to write the finish method in Backpressed method and onclick method also If you write this two it will work surely..

Answer (score 0):

just call onBackPressed() from ,

```
       public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
   if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
   // call here
      onBackPressed();
   }
   return true;
 }

             @Override
public void onBackPressed() {


// just write alertbox option here

   AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(Spinnermenu.this);
ab.setTitle("Power Options");
ab.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int choice) {
    if(choice == 0) {       
                Toast.makeText(Spinnermenu.this,"PowerOff Perform",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
//add,     
    finish();                    
    }
    else if(choice == 1) {
//add,

    finish();   

    }
});
ab.show();


}
```